# Is it possible to resize window to be larger than the desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, display, autohotkey

I have a program whose window size should be greater than the desktop because when maximized, it is still short of a few pixels at the right, making it hard to control scrollbar when the mouse cursor is located at the rightmost.

my laptop is with 1920x1080 resolution as default, and other programs but this don't have the issue for now.

the program is Akelpad, the simple text editor as Windows' bultin notepad replacement.
I asked around with no solution offered so I wish I can get some ideas here.

In short, I want this program window to be a few pixels bigger horizontally when maximized.

Comment: Assuming the host has the whole desktop, what you want is not possible. Try making the app a "window" and reduce in size with smaller fonts or something like that.

Comment: What does this have to do with autokey?

Comment: See [WinMove](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinMove.htm) and [A_ScreenWidth/A_ScreenHeight](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#Screen).

Comment: Is the issue that the window is not large enough when it is maximized, or that the application is poorly coded such that it is not properly fitting the various elements within the current window size. A will-written application will arrange its elements properly regardless the size of the application, particularly elements like a scrollbar, usually with a set lower limit (eg. too small to fit all the required elements).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the below? Just swap out "ahk_exe notepad.exe" with your WinTitle acquired through Window Spy...and adjust the values as needed for refinement.

```
#NoEnv 
#Persistent 
#SingleInstance, Force 

^!R::                        ; (Ctrl+Alt+R)
Resize("ahk_exe notepad.exe", -8, -5, 1935, 1080)        ; Notepad
Return


Resize(WinTitle, Xpos, Ypos, Width, Height) {
 WinGet Win, List, % WinTitle
 If (Win > 0) {
  Loop % Win { 
   WinRestore % W := "ahk_id" Win%A_Index%
   WinMove    % W,, Xpos, Ypos, Width, Height
  }
MsgBox 64, Resized, %WinTitle% `n`nWidth = %Width% and Height = %Height% `nPositioned at x %Xpos% and y %Ypos%
 } Else {
MsgBox, Error, "Window was not found.`n`n" %winTitle%
    }
}
Return


^Home:: 
    Reload
        Return
^Esc:: 
    ExitApp
        Return
```